# How to extract a specific string from a column

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I am trying to extract  a specific string that starts with 'A0' and give me back the string A0 along with the rest of 9 values from a column in a table . I need to extract an auth number in a claims notes column in a table.

I am trying to use the regexp_substr function. I want to extract any string that starts with 'A0' in the clm_notes column in the table .

```
SELECT 
regexp_substr(CLM_NOTES, '[^A0]+', 1,1) as auth_num
FROM claims_table
```

this is how the column looks in the table

```
Clm_notes column 
New Auth from auth - A071869573
```

The Desired  results I want is to extract the string that starts with 'A0'

A071869573

Comment: I have a question, the format of the output is consistent? I mean all of them have hyphens?

Comment: yes, the format is always the same .

Comment: Why do you need regexp?

Comment: This is the one function which seems to fit what I need but still not sure.

Comment: is it always on the same position? is the string lenth  always the same?

Comment: @hotfix thanks for letting me know. I did not see it was an Oracle db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like the following:

```
SELECT 
regexp_substr(CLM_NOTES, 'A0.*$', 1,1) as auth_num
FROM claims_table
```

Or perhaps if all characters after A0 are digits:

```
SELECT 
regexp_substr(CLM_NOTES, 'A0[0-9]*$', 1,1) as auth_num
FROM claims_table
```

Another faster way may be the following:

```
SELECT 
substr(CLM_NOTES, instr(CLM_NOTES,'A0')) as auth_num
FROM claims_table
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I am going to have to study up on why it worked . Thanks again.

Comment: May I suggest making the match as specific as possible to the data you are after in order to avoid false positives.  For example, match dash, space 'A0' when followed by 8 digits: `'- A0\d{8}'`.  Do you differentiate between admissions and referrals or is 'A' for auths in general?

Comment: Good point! Thanks Gary. I did not take that into account. I have updated the statement to avoid any issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than match what you want, match what you don't want and delete it:

```
select
    regexp_replace(CLM_NOTES, '.*- A0', 'A0') as auth_num
from claims_table
```

This matches everything before and including `'- A0'` and replaces it with just `'A0'`, effectively deleting everything preceding `'A0'`.